# how to extract single value from json in Golang?

Tags: json, go

### my code

```
func HostStats() (*host.InfoStat, error) {
   infoStat, err := host.Info()
   fmt.Printf("All Host info: ", infoStat)
   return infoStat, err
}
```

### output

`All Host info: %!(EXTRA string= {"hostname":"UDAY-PC","uptime":536323,"bootTime":1559911444,"procs":248,"os":"windows","platform":"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro","platformFamily":"Standalone Workstation","platformVersion":"10.0.17134 Build 17134","kernelVersion":"","virtualizationSystem":"","virtualizationRole":"","hostid":"0b324295-3631-47db-b6e8-83cdba2a1af9"})`

I want to parse and show the below value from above:

1. hostname
2. Platform
3. HostId

### I tried and below has the additional code:

```
func HostStats() (*host.InfoStat, error) {

infoStat, err := host.Info()

type Information struct {
    Name  string
    Platform string
    HostId  string
}

var info []Information
info, err := json.Unmarshal(infoStat, &info)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("ok: %+v", info)

//almost every return value is a struct
fmt.Printf("All Host info: ", infoStat)
return infoStat, err
}
```

Comment: Have you tried at all? Parsing JSON is a common task and there is a ton of information available through a simple web search and right here on SO. Do you have any code where you've attempted anything? Can you show that?

Comment: So, what issue are you having with that?

Comment: I have added my code which I tried @Adrian here is the error which I am getting: "no new variables on left side of :="

Comment: Right... `info` and `err` are already defined, exactly like the error says. Use `=` instead of `:=` to assign to variables that already exist. Basic Go syntax is covered pretty thoroughly in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian mentioned above, you are having problems with your Variables.

In Go you can initialize a variable like you did:

```golang
var info string
// And assign a value to it by:
info = "foo"
```

The Json is unmarshaled into your info variable. The return value of the json.Unmarshal is only an error. So the correct syntax would be:

```golang
var info []Information
err := json.Unmarshal(infoStat, &info)
```

So remember the different ways to initialize vars and assign values to those vars.
You can look at [GoDocs for Variables](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/4) for more Info :)